# Install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop over ssh (Ansible)?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ansible, remote

The computers in our classroom currently run a master system (Ubuntu 18.04 desktop) on one partition and a backup system (Ubuntu 16.04 desktop) on another partition.

How can I remotely (ssh or Ansible) install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop on one partition from home?

For the configuration and installation of software Ansible is already used.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect using `ssh` to ubuntu 18.04 and use `do-release-upgrade` command to upgrade to 20.04. You could do the same in 16.04, but then you would have to gradually upgrade, 16.04 -> 18.04 -> 20.04.

On the other hand it's a bit risky to upgrade release, it would be better to be near the machine in case something goes wrong (ie the sshd doesn't come up after reboot and cannot access it).

Check this link:
[upgrade 18.04 to 20.04](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today)

Comment: release upgrade is only available after the first point release has been released. This is due three months after the initial release, which should be end of july.

Comment: It is avaiable. It's not suggested by the ubuntu GUI auto-update mechanism, that'll happen after three months, but if you initiate the process by command it can be done.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. Normally I install e.g. Ubuntu 20.04 via USB stick and then run our Ansible scripts which configure the system and install software packages.
But at the moment I can't use a USB stick directly on site because I have to work from home. So I would like to somehow install Ubuntu 20.04 from remote.